# install apk on samsung tablet, but I cant find it?

Tags: android

I have installede a app I made. When I run it from eclipse it works, but I cant find it anywhere on my tablet, when I click program (where all the apps are, it is not there) but when I run programmangere I can see it is there. I tried to download it from link, and it install, but I can still not find it anywhere on my tablet.

Any ides??

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.learn2crack.tab"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_FORMAT_FILESYSTEMS"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.learn2crack.tab.MainActivity"

        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/html" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: post your android manifest file

Comment: remove <data> tag from your untent-filter tag and try again

Comment: Check if app_name in strings.xml is not empty

Comment: Mostly issue is with the app name in strings as pointed out

Answer (score 0):

First connect the tablet to your pc then copy your apk file which is in the bin then paste it in your phone memory. now disconnect your device.. Goto FileManager in your tablet find the .apk and click on it install it and then open it... Hope ths will work